¿Cómo establecer el set de caracteres como el que usaba MSDOS en una aplicación de consola C#?
Estoy programando una app de consola C# cómo parte de una aplicación grafica mas completa.
Quisiera poder cambiar lo mas posible la apariencia de la consola.
Entonces, me gustaria saber ¿Como puedo cambiar el set de caracteres en la app de consola C#, para colocarlo como el que tenía MSDOS, y así tenga los caracteres con los que pueda entonces pintar sombras y ventanas simples y dobles con esquinas y conjunciones?
Gracias. Un cordial saludo.

Me parece que lo que buscas es el Code page 437 (muy común en el paleolítico), el cual era una extensión del ASCII
Quizás existe una línea de código "mágica" que configura lo que tú quieres, yo creo que no es tan simple porque: En esencia lo que se tiene son bytes. La codificación toma esos bytes los agrupa, los ordena y los referencia a una tabla de valores para convertirlos a un glifo imprimible según la fuente usada
Por otro lado, C# (.net para ser más exactos) no tiene una consola, si no que imprime en la consola del sistema, esto lo hace stremiando bytes, por lo que para lograr lo que tú quieres tienes que:

Configurar la consola del sistema para establecer la codificación deseada (CP437), algo como mode con cp select=437 en Windows y por supuesto tener una fuente que tenga esos glifos.

Enviar desde C# esos caracteres en la codificación deseada, y creo que está es la parte compleja, porque en C# los char y los string están en UTF, es decir se almacenan con codificación, por lo que tu tendrás que trabajar a nivel de bytes, algo como:


Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance); //habilita el soporte para "Otros" códigos de páginas 
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437); //busca el CP 437

//imprime desde el código 32 al 255
for (int i = 32; i < 256; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetChars([(byte)i]));  //encoding.GetChars "encodea" un array de bytes
}


Mi recomendación es que trabajes directamente en UTF8 (unicode), para esto usas Verbatim text ( el @ antes del string) para facilitarte la vida. Luego copias y pegas los caracteres desde alguna tabla, por ejemplo, desde charmap.exe. De esta manera vas dibujando directamente en el código, algo así:
        Console.WriteLine(@"
  █████████████████████████████
┌────────────────────────────┐█
│                            │█
│                            │█
│          HOLA!!            │█
│                            │█
│                            │█
└────────────────────────────┘");

Salida:

